# Display range for RGB colors for imtool function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In a normal situation ,when I use,

```
l = imread('football.jpg');
```

First I separate the bands of colors

```
i = l(:,:,1);
j = l(:,:,2);
k = l(:,:,3);
```

Then I attach them back.

```
im(:,:,1) = i;
im(:,:,2) = j;
im(:,:,3) = k;
imtool(im);
```

This gives me a normal rgb image back , with each pixel position showing the pixel value.

Now my goal is to scaleup the rgb image , that is zoom it . So I first separate the bands from the rgb image. I do the 'zooming' of the pixels and then attach them back , using the same above procedure . However, this time when I call imtool(im) , I see no value of the pixels . I only white enlarged image . The pixel info that is  set at the bottom of the image is with in the range `0 1` in the format `[ r b g]` . Is there a way to increase that range . Just to note that when I use a single band instead of 3 bands together , and use `imtool(im , [ 0 255 ] )` , I see a pretty nice zoomed out picture . I just do not know how to use that same idea when I use the 3 bands together .

Edit:Just to make it clear :

```
   im(:,:,1) = sampleUp(i,p);
   %im(:,:,2) = sampleUp(j,p);
   %im(:,:,3) = sampleUp(k,p);

   imshow(im,[0 255]);( in octave) 

   imtool(im ,[0 255]);(in matlab)
```

The above code works nice for displaying a scaled up gray scale image , not an rgb image . I know I am missing something fundamental here . I would be happy , if somebody can figure me out that ,

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using imresize with nearest neighbour interpolation?

```
I = imread('rice.png');
J = imresize(I, 2, 'nearest');
figure, imshow(I), figure, imshow(J)
```

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html

Comment: Ha , I am supposed to implement imresize() function , according to my instructor , forgot to mention that . The pixels values are not showing up when I try to do anything on the pixels and show it using imtool() . Also forgot to mention , when my function works for gray scale image , I have to adjust the contrast from the upper menu ,in order to see the pixels . In rgb , that option is hidden from the image window menu , so I can't use it .

Answer (score 0):

Rescale the display range.

```
imshow(image,[min(min(mean)),max(max(mean))]);
```